# Avoiding reprojection gaps when merging DEM rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, merge, saga

I have two raster DEMs in same resolution I want to bring together. I was using the merge-function in SAGA, GRASS and QGIS but I always get the following result:

[image]

Where could the fault be?

Comment: Are the DEMs still in their original CRS? Looks like a reprojection gap.

Comment: Or possibly a tiling artifact in the original data.  I've seen this sort of thing many times with data from Ordnance Survey and the error is in how OS tiled the data and not in the merging process.  It could be a similar thing here.

Comment: It might be worth making a virtual raster (*.vrt) from the two DEMs to see if you still get the same problem with this (Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster). N.

Comment: Same with vitual raster...one of the DEMs are reprojected....

Comment: Can you test if this is the same problem? http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-merge-py-on-large-Tiff-s-gdalwarp-not-working-properly-td4986729.html

Comment: Can the two DEMs be downloaded from somewhere Martin?

Comment: Have you tried the virtual raster with unreprojected DEMs? I guess they are from the same source.

Comment: They are from different source. Maybe thats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should **first** mosaik the map tiles, **then** perform the reprojection. This will avoid the gaps unless they already exist in the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment but I believe markusN is refering to running:

```
gdalbuildvrt OUTPUT.img.vrt DEM_1 DEM_2 DEM_N
```

FWIW, this is what I do in my workflow to avoid visible seams at tile boundaries.